# Webpack loaders throwin error even with proper config

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack loaders aren't working, so here goes all the issue information

```
OS: windows 10
node: 8.2.1
npm: 5.3.0
```

the console error message when I try to run `npm run dev` :

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.1.6 and C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\angular-project\tsconfig.json


#
# Fatal error in api.cc, line 1200
# Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

        v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex [0x00007FF7113BF426+8086]
        v8::Template::Set [0x00007FF710EF9FAD+349]
        Nan::SetPrototypeTemplate [0x00007FFED066DBA3+131] (c:\mamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\angular-project\node_modules\nan\nan.h:1847)
        SassTypes::Boolean::get_constructor [0x00007FFED0672E99+329] (c:\mamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\angular-project\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp:26)
        SassTypes::Factory::initExports [0x00007FFED0675B19+489] (c:\mamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\angular-project\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\factory.cpp:55)
        node_module_register [0x00007FF710C47745+2437]
        v8::internal::interpreter::Interpreter::GetDispatchCountersObject [0x00007FF7114A1C20+54448]
        std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::zone_allocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Reallocate [0x00007FF710FE1598+113688]
        std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::zone_allocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Reallocate [0x00007FF710FE0453+109267]
        std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::zone_allocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Reallocate [0x00007FF710FE033B+108987]
        (No symbol) [0x000002040D6840C1]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! halo-effect@0.0.1 dev: `npm run clean && webpack --config=webpack-dev.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the halo-effect@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wagner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-24T14_40_15_990Z-debug.log
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 34:  3084 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

`npm list webpack` is returning empty but it is inside node_modules as version 1.13.1 as is listed on package.json file:

```
$ npm list webpack
project-name@0.0.1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\angular-project
`-- (empty)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "generator": "node generator.js",
    "clean": "rm -f ../halo-wordpress-theme/css/* && rm -f ../halo-wordpress-theme/js/*",
    "dev": "npm run clean && webpack --config=webpack-dev.config.js",
    "release": "npm run clean && webpack --config=webpack-release.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "1.6.27",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "1.4.4",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "1.5.10",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "1.1.37",
    "@types/es6-shim": "0.31.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasmine-matchers": "0.2.30",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.71",
    "@types/ng-dialog": "0.6.2",
    "@types/ng-file-upload": "12.2.1",
    "angular": "1.6.5",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.5",
    "angular-mocks": "1.6.5",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "1.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "clipboard": "1.7.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "ng-dialog": "1.3.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.2.13",
    "ng-infinite-scroll": "1.3.0",
    "ngclipboard": "1.1.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "precss": "2.0.0",
    "sass-lint": "1.10.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "sasslint-webpack-plugin": "1.0.4",
    "string": "3.3.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "ts-loader": "2.3.1",
    "tslint": "5.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.4",
    "vorpal": "1.12.0",
    "webpack": "1.13.1"
  }
}
```

webpack-dev-config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var loaders = require("./webpack-loaders");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');
var sassLintPlugin = require('sasslint-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, '../myproject-wordpress-theme/js/')
};

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  watch: true,
  debug: true,
  entry: {
    app: [
      PATHS.app
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.dist,
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: function(info) {
      return "file:///"+info.absoluteResourcePath;
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.scss']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: loaders
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'fonts/', to: '../fonts/'}
    ]),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new sassLintPlugin({
      configFile: '.sass-lint.yml',
      ignoreFiles: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/common/footer.scss'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/common/normalize.scss')
      ],
      glob: 'src/**/*.s+(a|c)ss',
      ignorePlugins: ['extract-text-webpack-plugin']
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack-loaders.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader?-url!postcss-loader"),
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader?-url!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded")
  }
];
```